# How to create and write to a file based on the latest timestamp condition from a json file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a part of the big json file I have. I am creating folders with the content from `yamlPath` and then writing to a file with the content from `sqlQuery`. But in the case of repeating "yamlName+yamlPath", my code is only creating the file with the first result and inserting the `sqlQuery` content it gets from the for loop. So, in this repeating scenario, I only want to pick up the `sqlQuery` and create a file based on the latest/max `jobEndTimestamp`.

How can  make the code to pick up only the latest `jobEndTimestamp` and create the file?

Expected output:

```
/app/computer/users/ship-notice-data.sql   -> select from table.b
/app/computer/a/users/boat-notice-data.sql -> select from table.b
```

```
{
"stream": [
{
  "applicationServiceId": "uhhj",
  "yamlName": "/users/ship-notice-data.yml",
  "yamlPath": "/app/computer",
  "jobStartTimestamp": "2018-09-15 04:12:46",
  "jobEndTimestamp": "2018-09-15 04:15:29",
  "sourceHostName": "Teradata",
  "sourceType": "Teradata",
  "targetHostName": "DB2",
  "targetType": "DB2",
  "sqlQuery": "select from table.a"
},{
  "applicationServiceId": "uhhj",
  "yamlName": "/users/ship-notice-data.yml",
  "yamlPath": "/app/computer",
  "jobStartTimestamp": "2018-09-15 21:12:46",
  "jobEndTimestamp": "2018-09-15 21:15:29",
  "sourceHostName": "Teradata",
  "sourceType": "Teradata",
  "targetHostName": "DB2",
  "targetType": "DB2",
  "sqlQuery": "select from table.b"
},{
  "applicationServiceId": "uhhj",
  "yamlName": "/users/car-notice-data.yaml",
  "yamlPath": "/app/computer/s",
  "jobStartTimestamp": "2018-09-15 04:12:46",
  "jobEndTimestamp": "2018-09-15 06:15:29",
  "sourceHostName": "Teradata",
  "sourceType": "Teradata",
  "targetHostName": "DB2",
  "targetType": "DB2",
  "sqlQuery": "select from table.b"
},{
  "applicationServiceId": "uhhj",
  "yamlName": "/users/boat-notice-data.yaml",
  "yamlPath": "/app/computer/a",
  "jobStartTimestamp": "2018-09-15 04:12:46",
  "jobEndTimestamp": "2018-09-15 06:15:29",
  "sourceHostName": "Teradata",
  "sourceType": "Teradata",
  "targetHostName": "DB2",
  "targetType": "DB2",
  "sqlQuery": "select from table.b"
}
]
}
```

here is my code:

```
with open('/Users/mona/stream.json', 'r') as f:
    item_dict = json.load(f)

for item in item_dict['stream']:
    if (item['applicationServiceId'] == 'uhhj' and 
            item.get('targetHostName') == 'DB2' and
            (item['targetType'] == 'DB2')):
        # print(item.get('applicationServiceId'))
        v3 = item.get('applicationServiceId')
        v4 = item.get('jobEndTimestamp')
        v = item.get('sqlQuery')
        v1 = item.get('yamlName')
        v2 = item.get('yamlPath')
        print(v1+v2+" "+v4+ " " +str(v))
        # v4 = str(item.get('yamlName').split('/')[-1].split('.')[0])
        # print(v4)

        originalPath = "/Users/mona/"

        fullPath = os.path.join(originalPath+v2+(v1.split('/')[1].split('/')[0])+'/'+(v1.split('/')[2].split('/')[0])+'/')
        # print(fullPath)
        os.makedirs(fullPath, mode=0o777, exist_ok=True)
        # print(v1)

        with open(fullPath + str(item.get('yamlName').split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]) + ".sql", "w") as newFile:
            newFile.write("%s \n" % (v))
```

Comment: you might want to consider using a library like [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for something like this

Comment: @wpercy I really don't see why pandas is helpful here. Can you elaborate on what you're thinking?

Comment: couldn't you group by `"yamlName+yamlPath"` and then filter on `max(jobEndTimestamp)` and take the query value from there? obviously it can just be done with a sort or filter, but I thought it'd be easier with pandas

Comment: @wpercy can you please help me writing the group and filter function? I am trying but not having any luck. thanks for your help

Comment: @Mona just posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution is sub-optimal, but It could work...

The idea is to group the dictionary by `yamlPath`, and each path, contains a list of dictionaries, with `yamlPath`.

then, you split, and rejoin the path, and save the name, (so It's compatible, with your OS), and then, in the end, I'm just opening the context so you can append to that file you just open (created in case it doesn't exist, or open and appending in case it does that is why the `'a'` parameter).

```
from collections import defaultdic
import os
objects = defaultdic(list)

for item in item_dict['stream']:
    objects[item.yamlPath].append(item)
for yamlPath in objects.keys():
    for item in yamlPath:
        temp = yamlPath.split("/") + item.yamlName.split("/")[:-1]
        name = item.yamlName.split("/")[-1]
        file_with_path = os.path.join(*temp)
        with open(os.path.join(*temp, name), 'a') as file:
            pass # Do what ever to the content
```

Again, this is Just an Idea that It might work, (haven't tried it) And you have trouble creating the dirs, but If the problem still is the time stamps, follow the same logic as this, and group them by the time stamp you want, and then just iterate over the `max(objects.keys())` (assuming these dates are comparable if not just cast them)

Answer (score 0):

To do this with pandas you can create a dataframe with your data, add a new column called `fullPath` group by that and then filter to the max `jobEndTimestamp`. Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('/Users/mona/stream.json', 'r') as f:
    item_dict = json.load(f.read())

df = pd.DataFrame(item_dict['sources'])
df['fullPath'] = df['yamlPath'] + df['yamlName']
grouped = df.groupby('fullPath').apply(lambda d: d[d['jobEndTimestamp'] == d['jobEndTimestamp'].max()])

print grouped['sqlQuery']
```

will yield

```
fullPath
/app/computer/a/users/boat-notice-data.yaml  3    select from table.b
/app/computer/s/users/car-notice-data.yaml   2    select from table.b
/app/computer/users/ship-notice-data.yml     1    select from table.b
Name: sqlQuery, dtype: object
```